# Obtaining currently logged-in user's model

Tags: php, yii, model

Is there a better (more professional or more secure?) way of doing this, than:

```
$user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
```

I assume (correct me, if I'm wrong), Yii does not hold entire user model in `Yii::app()->user`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't out of the box. But you can easily do it your own.
Take this as reference in WebUser.php

```
class WebUser
{
    protected $model;

    [...] // more code

    public function getModel()
    {
        if ($this->model === null)
        {
            if (!$this->isGuest)
            {
                $this->model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
            }
        }

        return $this->model;
    }

    [...] // more code
}
```

Then you can do Yii::app()->user->model;

Comment: Perfect solution! I've just came with the very same, though I wanted to put it to `User` (`User::getCurrentUserModel`). Doing this in `WebUser` is, obviously, much better. Thank you!

Comment: On second thought... I don't want to turn out to be ignorant, but why we're using protected variable here? I was always using private variables (`$_model` in this case) in case of getters / setters in models.

Comment: There is no special reason for this. I like to use protected over private in most cases because it's a bit more flexible, especially when it comes to unit testing. But you are right, private might be the better choice here.